# Using methods from the "outer" class in inner classes

Tags: java

When defining nested classes, is it possible to access the "outer" class' methods? I know it's possible to access its attributes, but I can't seem to find a way to use its methods.

```
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && //<-- Here I'd like to
        }                                 // reference a method
    });                                   //from the class where
                                          //addMouseListener() is defined!
```

Thanks

Comment: It should just work. What compiler error did you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your inner class is non-static, all methods of the outer class are automatically visible to the inner class, even private ones.

So, just go ahead and call the method that you want.

For example,

```
   class MyClass extends JPanel
   {

        void doStuff()
        {
        }

        boolean someLogic()
        {
           return 1>2;
        }

        void setupUI() 
        {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                 if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && someLogic())
                   doStuff();
               }
            });                                
        }
    }
```

For more on this, see the [Sun Tutorial on Nested Classes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: Ah, you're right. My mistake was trying to do this. to try to see what methods were available in the IDE.

Comment: `1>2`? That isn't logical! ;)

Comment: it's logical - it just isn't true. ;-)  (I guess someone's going to quote me a scene from Star Trek or aomething now...)

Answer (score 3):

There is another trick for using outer-class references in inner-classes, which I often use:

```
class OuterClass extends JFrame {

    private boolean methodName() {
        return true;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // uses the local defined method
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               System.out.println(methodName()); // false
               // localclass method
               System.out.println(OuterClass.this.methodName()); // true
               // outerclass method
               OuterClass.super.addMouseListener(this); // don't run this, btw
               // uses the outerclasses super defined method
           }
           private boolean methodName() {
               return false;
           }
        });                                
    }

    @Override
    public void addMouseListener(MouseListener a) {
        a.mouseClicked(null);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Failing everything else you could define a self reference attribute :

`MyClass current = this;`

and use that..

Though I would also like to know the true, clean, answer to your question!

Comment: Ah, that sure is a nice idea!

Comment: If you mean to put that in the inner class, that's not quite right - the 'this' pointer will point to the inner class. To get the outer class this pointer, you have to qualify it with the outer class name, e.g. OuterClass.this.

Comment: Agreed, I think you may have misunderstood - we're talking about declaring the self reference in the outer class, and using it in the inner class - as mentioned the outer class attributes can be accessed from the inner class.

Comment: If using `Outer.this` is too cumbersome for you, you *might* do this, but I would call it `outer` not `current` and declare it in the inner class.  Personally I *hate* the implicit access to the outer class (it's way too easy to screw things up with any other than trivial classes), so I usually use a static class with an explicit member variable called outer and pass the outer class instance as a parameter during construction.

Comment: @Software Monkey: static outer class with manual inner class reference, +1. Great suggestion!